# Handle Async Operations in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have been using the `async` package from NPM inside my Node.js service to run different operations in sequence. Example: when I would like to run `functionA`, `functionB`, `functionC` in sequence. I would use `Promise` in Node.js, but this means using callbacks which are not that efficient when we have lot of functions which need to run in sequence.

I have recently familiarized myself with Reactive Programming using `Observable`s and this is widely being used in frontend frameworks such as AngularJS and React. I was wondering if Node.js has something similar to that and if there are any better ways to handle async operations in sequence.

Comment: Why not [install RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage) in your Node project? Reactive programming is as usable on the server-side as it is on the client-side.

Comment: I would think that any reactive mechanism also uses callbacks.